# How to add 2 Textures without a seam

Tags: texturing

[image]How to get this kind of seamless transition between two textures?
I have tried adding two textures to one object but can see a seam. Any solution for that seamless transition?

Comment: create a black and white image that you'll use as mask between your 2 shaders?

Comment: Use a mask to help blend your bump map details into the texture, I don't think you'll need two separate shaders since it's all the same plastic.

Comment: I don't know how to do that can you add a screenshot or something?